# How do I access properties of an APEX2JSON object returned from an APEX API request method in Javascript?

Tags: apex, javascript

I am trying to access the results of an API request (handled in an APEX class) in Javascript.
I am using JSON2APEX to map the results to an APEX object.

MY Object mapping class looks like this:

```
public with sharing class WrapperResponse {


public class Result
{
    public final Integer status;
    public final String message;
    public final List<ComplianceRecord> complianceRecords;
    public final String clientId;
}

public class ComplianceRecord{
    public final String pairStatus;
    public final String  pairReason;
}
```

}

Here is my APEX request method which seems to work:

```
public with sharing class LWCRest {
@AuraEnabled
public static WrapperResponse.Result LWCRestMethod(){
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
    httpRequest.setEndpoint('URL');
    httpRequest.setMethod('POST');
    httpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpRequest.setHeader('Accept','application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml');
    httpRequest.setHeader('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate');
    httpRequest.setHeader('Host',HOST URL);
    // Set the body as a JSON object
    httpRequest.setBody(BODY);
    String strResponse = null;
    try {  
      Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);  
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
                strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();  
            } 
            else {  
                throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());  
            } 
         
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) {  
            throw ex;  
        } 
     if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
        WrapperResponse.Result results = (WrapperResponse.Result)JSON.deserialize(
            strResponse,  WrapperResponse.Result.class
        );
            return results;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
}
```

}

The issue comes with my JS class which calls `LWCRest` but I am not sure how to access the response properties in the way in which JSON2APEX is supposed to allow:

```
 handleFetch(){

    restdatapull().then(results => {

     console.log (results+ "Hiiii");
     for (const key in results){
      
          console.log(`${key} : ${res[key]}`) //NOTHING GETS LOGGED HERE
        
      }

    }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    });
    
}
```

I am thinking that I somehow need to cast result to the APEX object type, but deployment fails when I try import it from APEX.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: If you're not getting errors and nothing gets logged, it could be a quirk I've found where for whatever reason, when I've tried to send a result back to an LWC in the form of a custom Apex object, nothing gets returned.  Maybe it's to do with not having @AuraEnabled decorators on the custom class, but I'm not sure (this only just occurred to me).  I've found that sending a string of the serialized object back to the LWC, then deserializing it in the JavaScript works fine.  Might be worth giving that a go.

Comment: Try decorating the apex class and attributes with `@auraEnabled`

Comment: @VictorL. so this worked at the very least, but obviously not the elegant approach I was hoping to take.

Comment: Yeah, it really isn't.  Hopefully someone else will be able to chime in with a better answer, but it'll tide you over in the meantime I suppose.